# Creating an elastic index using Nest

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I use elasticsearch a lot at work (from Python) but wanted to roll it into a little .Net project I'm doing in my spare time. A quick wander through NuGet brought me to [Nest](https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST).

I'm defining my "model" as follows...

```
<ElasticType(Name:="Document")>
Public Class Document
    Property UserId As Long
    <ElasticProperty(IndexAnalyzer:="not_analyzed")>
    Property Something As String
    Property EmailAddress As String
End Class
```

and then attempting to create and index like this...

```
Dim Ret = ES.CreateIndex(IndexName,
               Function(x) x.AddMapping(Of Document)(
                   Function(m) m.MapFromAttributes))
If Not Ret.OK Then
    With Ret.ConnectionStatus.Error
        Throw New Exception(String.Format("Failed to create index ({0}): {1}", .HttpStatusCode, .ExceptionMessage))
    End With
End If
```

And I'm getting `Failed to create index (BadRequest): MapperParsingException[mapping [Document]]; nested: MapperParsingException[Analyzer [not_analyzed] not found for field [something]];`

I've tried both

```
<ElasticProperty(Analyzer:="not_analyzed")>
```

and

```
<ElasticProperty(IndexAnalyzer:="not_analyzed")>
```

What I'm trying to get it to build is json equivalent to

```
"something" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
```

as shown in the [es docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html).

What am I missing?

(Elastic 0.90.6)

Comment: Can you post the actual http request that is made to the elasticsearch server along with the query parameters?

Comment: @geeky_sh I've just found where that's stored (I hadn't spotted it before) and You've pointed me in the right direction. Thank you! I'll post details as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an attribute property I missed which handles this...

```
<ElasticType(Name:="Document")>
Public Class Document
    Property UserId As Long
    <ElasticProperty(Index:=FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed)>
    Property Something As String
    Property EmailAddress As String
End Class
```

Note the `Index` property which takes an Enum. Thanks to @geeky_sh for prompting me to look in the right place.

Comment: Elasticsearch log file will complain with: `Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Analyzer [not_analyzed] not found for field`.